# I am confused about jinja2 in saltstack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I read the state file about vim-formula on github --> [Here](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/vim-formula)

There is a file named salt.sls  ：

```
{% from "vim/map.jinja" import vim with context %}
include:
  - vim
sakt_vimfiles:
  file.recurse:
    - name: {{ vim.share_dir }}
    - source: salt://vim/files/salt
```

But I couldn't find  `vim.sls` which included in `salt.sls` in current directory.I learned the guidbook in saltstack's website,and I know the word `include` means to reuse a state file,right?

So I think it must be related to the jinja2 `{% from "vim/map.jinja" import vim with context %}`

and map.jinja :

```
{% set vim = salt['grains.filter_by']({
'Arch': {
    'pkg': 'vim',
    'share_dir': '/usr/share/vim/vimfiles',
    'group': 'root',
    'config_root': '/etc',
},
'Debian': {
    'pkg': 'vim',
    'share_dir': '/usr/share/vim/vimfiles',
    'group': 'root',
    'config_root': '/etc/vim',
},
'RedHat': {
    'pkg': 'vim-enhanced',
    'share_dir': '/usr/share/vim/vimfiles',
    'group': 'root',
    'config_root': '/etc',
},
'Suse': {
    'pkg': 'vim',
    'share_dir': '/usr/share/vim/site',
    'group': 'root',
    'config_root': '/etc',
},
'FreeBSD': {
    'pkg': 'vim',
    'share_dir': '/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles',
    'group': 'wheel',
    'config_root': '/etc',
},
}, merge=salt['pillar.get']('vim:lookup')) %}
```

Comment: the words `include: - vim ` in salt.sls.where is the `- vim`?

Comment: Ah,I think it does not matter with jinja2 now ,and the `vim.sls` state file lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must agree, it is insane to read Jinja. And it is even WORST if you are a newbie for salt file structure. It is all about the poor emphasize on basic inside the documentation that cause confusion. Indeed, you need to understand many basic saltstack setup structure to avoid confusion.

Now to the answer .

Imagine you copy the whole formula folder to your salt-states folder, say your (salt master configuration `/etc/salt/master`) `files_root`: are `/srv/salt/states`

Actually, the formula ASSUME you copy the github formula source /vim folder under the file roots. Thus you should have something like `/srv/salt/states/vim`.

Now come to the fun part : the files_roots is `/srv/salt/states`, so for salt-master file-system, anything start from the folder are consider `salt://` . And since your vim folder is under it, so it will be refer as `salt://vim`.

Now back to your `salt.sls` in the `/srv/salt/states/vim`, it have no problem finding the `include : - vim`

The [Saltstatck Get started](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/)  is much better for beginner to start with. Just repeat the tutorial for a few time, it will help solve most of the confusion.

(more) 
Again another basic : **How saltstack traverse folder**. This also explain how the include find the correct file.
If you have something like this

```
base:
  myserver:
    - app
    - db.myserver
```

So for the first `app`, there is two ways to write the state
First way : put the state into `app.sls`
Second way : create a **folder** call `app` , then put the state into `app/init.sls`

The first way is straightforward. The second way is kinda "magic" if you didn't read the basic. In fact,  `init.sls` is the state file. You can put many `.sls` inside the `app` folder. But salt don't care about other, unless you call them explicit, i.e. , as in the example, `db.server`

```
# This is the first way, direct reference to the sls file
+--app.sls
+--/db
   +--myserver.sls 

# Second way, using init.sls as anchor inside folder.
+--/app
   +-- init.sls
+--/db
   +--/myserver
      +--init.sls
```

So come to Second way `db.server`
Now this look straightforward, salt master just traverse into `salt://db/` folder, look for `server.sls`. 
However, mix with the first way, you should know, You may write the state file into `/db/server/init.sls`, that's how salt looks for the file.

Now, go back to your vim formula folder, just read the `/vim/init.sls`. Now you understand the `include: vim` mean traverse into `salt://vim/init.sls` OR `salt://vim.sls` .

You may ask, what if mix both structure? My suggestion : Don't do it. You will confuse yourself and those who maintain your saltstack .

Comment: So,`include : - vim` means we use the whole vim folder?I think that the file included by  `include` just the file end with `.sls` but not a folder.and yeah I read the `Saltstack Get started` about `include`,but it doesn't solve my confusion.

Comment: @thorsiv : There is another basic, I just update by question.

Comment: :thanks for your patience.And I found the difference between `file.sls` and `file/init.sls`,I am so careless that I ignore the words in `SLS File Namespace` in https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/states_pt1.html and I think `init.sls` is helpful to manage state file.I will try. Thanks again.